# How to make a Discord Bot that can accept arguments from Python of what message to send to who and be able to close itself?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do something pretty simple. I just want Python to be able to call a quick function that sends a direct message over Discord. Basically a modified version of the [FAQ example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm). I want another Python class to start the Discord client and pass the message string and user id. And I want the Discord client to simply send the string and then close and delete the entire class. After looking through docs I made these modifications:

```
import discord
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        user = await self.fetch_user(self.destination_user)
        await user.send(self.message)
        await self.close()
    def __init__(self, user_id, user_message):
        self.destination_user = user_id
        self.message = user_message

client = MyClient(desired_id, desired_message)
client.run('My Client ID')
#wait for client to end and then continue
```

However, I'm running into 2 problems. It looks like discord.Client doesn't allow an `__init__()` function, and when I try to do async def `__init__()` there's also an error. Are there other ways to pass arguments to it through **Python**, rather than react to messages in Discord? Also, `self.close()` results in `"RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop"`. What's the proper way to wait for `on_ready()` to finish and then close it?

I can get it working by hardcoding the user ID and message, eliminating `__init__()` and simply not closing the class. However, for some reason, even then `self.get_user()` doesn't work, only `self.fetch_user()`. The docs say to use `get_user()`, so I'd prefer that, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My bot is in the same server as the target user, and I've given it both privileged intents, but `get_user()` continues to return "None", whereas `fetch_user()` properly messages the user, with the same exact arguments.

Comment: " just want Python to be able to call a quick function that sends a direct message over Discord"
In this case, your `MyClient` class should have (or inherit) a method that does it, it makes no sense to send a message on a Client class construction.

Comment: @ChristianH, so I should add a custom function called through Python that sends the message. However, there are no cases in the docs or Github examples that show how to call a custom function of a class that implements `discord.Client`. Once I call `client.run()`, that line blocks, and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: In my understanding, a client object can/should have a method to send messages. Implementing a class requires an interface, I don't think that's the case, I think you are extending/overriding a class. I have never used the python discord module, and I quickly checked the code and the method to send private messages is `send_private_message`, you can find it here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/1bf7aadf943844ed5970a9d44b73d1d67b790b08/discord/http.py#L340 . There is also a note in `fetch_user` method that you can check.

Comment: In my understanding, as you want to create your own class, I would do my own client, using an discord.Client instance in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what seems the proper way to run `discord.Client` in this fashion:

```
import discord
import nest_asyncio
import asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        user = await self.fetch_user(self.send_user)
        await user.send(self.message)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        #Pause so there's no warning about operations not finishing when class closes
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        await DiscordClient.close(self)
        
    async def parameters(self, user, message):
        self.send_user = user
        self.message = message

async def send_discord(user, message):
    print("Sending Discord message")
    client = DiscordClient()
    await client.parameters(user, message)
    await client.start('Private Key')
    print("Discord message sent")

asyncio.run(send_discord(user_id, "Test message contents"))
```

`on_message` runs even it's the bot that sent the message, so it will quickly close itself. I had to add the wait or there were some race conditions or something causing a warning every time it closed.